# Implementing RSS Feed from another site

Tags: wordpress, rss

Ok i've seen a lot of blogs do this but i cannot seem to figure out how they do it.

Check out ---> http://PopSugar.com

on the sidebar they implement feeds from other sites along with the thumbnail. They aren't using wordpress but there are some wordpress blogs that does the same.

Does anyone knows how I can do that too on my wordpress blog?

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the code yourself, here is a tutorial:
http://digwp.com/2009/11/import-and-display-feeds-in-wordpress/

or here are some existing plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/

http://www.iconophobia.com/wordpress/?page_id=55

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I have used a WordPress plugin that does exactly that you want. Here is the URL

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-posts-order/

By using this plugin you need to select XML/RSS feed option. But you can only display Post title.